# Не получается создать объект JSON

Tags: json, javascript

С сервера приходит json в таком виде:

```
{
data:   [
    {
        "id": "7",
        "name": "Современные вызовы",
        "author": "Олег Калюжин",
        "theme": "Медицинская",
        "publisher": "Медицинское информационное агентство",
        "year": "2002",
        "count_page": "340",
        "price": "1200",
        "img": "7.jpg"
    },
    {
        "id":"6",
        "name": "Психологические рисуночные тесты",
        "author": "Вася Пупкин",
        "theme": "Книги для родителей",
        "publisher": "АСТ",
        "year": "2013",
        "count_page": "176",
        "price": "890",
        "img": "6.jpg"
    }
]
}
```

при получении данных пытаюсь создать сам массив объектов,

```
var x = new XMLHttpRequest();
...
var obj = eval(x.responseText);
```

Когда вывожу алертом тип obj - `alert(typeof obj)`, то выводит тип `object`.

Теперь хочу работать с этим массивом объектов, например надо вывести название(name) первого элемента.

Дела. это так (не уверен, что правильно):

```
alert(obj.data[0].name);
```

Беда... Беда нечего не выводит, `alert(typeof obj.data[0].name)` => undefined

В консоли ошибок браузера, выводиться это `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined`

Answer (score 1):

Ваш верный помощник - это console.log:

```
var obj = eval(x.responseText);
console.log(obj);
```

и JSON.parse

```
var obj = JSON.parse(x.responseText);
```

в случае использования eval происходит не "распарсить строку в объект", а "применить строку кода", какой именно алгоритм при этом происходит - я точно не скажу, но предположу, что все свойства объекта превратятся в свойства window. При этом eval - это именно *применить* строку кода, само его использование в таком виде некорректно (корректно было бы `obj = json string`), и у меня сейчас отказывается "применять" простенький объект.